# How to pass multiples states at the same time to a child component from parent component in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to Reactjs and thanks in advance.
I have the states below:

```
const [firstName, setFirstName]=useState();
const [lastName, setLastName]=useState();
```

I want to pass both `firstName` and `lastName` to the child component from the parent component at the same time. How could I do that?

Comment: Please show the other component. You can pass them as props right

Comment: I don't see the point in asking such a basic question. A quick [google search](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=react+how+to+pass+state) can give you an answer to your question almost immediately. Please do at least a bit of research before asking a question here.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way, assuming that your components are called `Parent` and  `Child`:

```js
export default function Parent(){
   const [firstName, setFirstName]=useState();
   const [lastName, setLastName]=useState();
   
   return (
     <Child firstName={firstName} lastName={lastName} />
   )

}
```

And you get them inside `Child` like so:

```js
export default function Child(props){

  console.log(props.firstName, props.lastName)
  return <div></div>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you want to pass firstName and lastName to child element, relevant to component where you declared the states then you just need to pass them as props

```
<Child firstName={firstName} lastName={lastName} />
```

and inside child you would access them like props

```
function Child(props){

console.log(props) //this will show props of child component, there are stored your statements

return(...something here...)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See the react docs for [components and props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

> Components accept arbitrary inputs (called “props”) and return React elements describing what should appear on the screen.

> When React sees an element representing a user-defined component, it passes JSX attributes (and children) to this component as a single object. We call this object “props”.

```
import { useState } from "react";

function ParentComponent() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("John");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("Smith");
  return (
    <div className="ParentComponent">
      <ChildComponent firstName={firstName} lastName={lastName} />
    </div>
  );
}

function ChildComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div className="ChildComponent">
      <p>firstName: {props.firstName}</p>
      <p>lastName: {props.lastName}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-golick-9l49g?file=/src/App.js)